# Search by multiple values in angular using filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, search, ecmascript-6, ng-filter

i'd like to be able to search through multiple properties like the product name, the product info, the product price etc by typing in an input field.

what i currently have is this:

search field:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search by product name or info">
```

simple table with products:

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="prod in menuCtrl.menusProd | filter:search">
    <td>{{prod.name}}</td>
    <td>{{prod.info}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

what i'm trying to achive is to be able to search typing multiple values in the search bar, because at the moment it only searches for one in any of the fields (name or info not both).

for example if i have 2 products like:

```
var products = [
   { name: "pizza", info: "salami"},
   { name: "pizza", info: "cheese" }
];
```

how can i search giving multiple values like "pizza cheese" in the search-bar (so both name and info with space between words).

i think i found the example i need but i can't manage to replicate it in es6: http://plnkr.co/edit/scuPYt?p=preview

Comment: You linked a plunker with the exact solution. I don't get why you would replicate in es6. Could you post your code?
Another solution could be a custom filter:
https://jsfiddle.net/alfredopacino/5rxqaLxh/1/

Comment: it's not the exact solution since it doesn't search for 2 words, anyway i found this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Aowec7MzflOdPjPRgVHE?p=preview which is what i really needed. I'll try later to use a custom filter as you pointed out since it's a more clean way. @alfredopacino